# Laptop battery charges only on low or medium battery percent and automatically stops at 100%

Tags: 20.04, power-management, laptop, battery, indicator

So basically, I have an "Asus E402S" Model Laptop. I installed "Ubuntu 20.04 LTS" on it about a week ago. After installation and using it for some time, I noticed a problem that i never had while using windows 10. My battery starts charging only when the percentage of battery left is somewhere below 50%. And when I mean by not charging I meant not even the battery indicator shows when it is above 50%. Below 50% it charges fine and and all the way till 100% no issue. But after it fully charges, the battery indicator automatically turns off and will not charge again until it is below 50%, even when it fully in shutdown. Is there some preinstalled software or code in Ubuntu that controls your charging or is it just me. If there is preinstalled software, how can I control it? Waiting for the answers. Thank you.

Comment: UPDATE : I just went to a tech repair shop, found out my charger was dead. I bought a new charger and now my laptop is charging fine. Ubuntu was not doing anything to the battery.